# pcs.; or pcs; when used in a list

Tags: punctuation

I am not sure which is the correct form to use when writing a list of products. I need the semi-colon but do I need the full stop?

pcs.;
pcs;
Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid this question doesn't make much sense to me as it is written. Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: 'pc' is ordinarily the abbreviation for 'piece', not product, and only in the sense of 'unit'. Its use in prices (e.g. $1/pc) is very oldfashioned now; 'ea' (for 'each') is more common.

Answer (score 1):

Although using a full stop to indicate abbreviation is quite common, it is discouraged by some style guidelines such as [The University of Oxford's](http://www.ox.ac.uk/public_affairs/services_and_resources/style_guide/index.html), which explicitly states: 'Don’t use full stops after any abbreviations'.

If you do use a full stop to indicate abbreviation, then you should continue to do this when listing abbreviations. This applies when you are separating list items with commas (as is usual) or semicolons.

Comment: This varies by region. The United States almost invariably uses periods for abbreviations, while Britain doesn't.